# Theme development issue: WooCommerce cart and checkout does work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I'm currently working on a theme that is compatible with WooCommerce, I started to create and customize single and archive pages, but when I got to the cart and checkout page, the pages not working and when u open the links, instead of cart the index page will show up.

Answer (score 0):

So i Just found the solution for it . just Create page.php file in you theme root directory and customize it for blog single page , then the cart and checkout pages will work fine.
Hope it Helps !!!